# Use one class in a different class (basic oop understanding)?

Tags: ruby, oop, object

I've been working with ruby for quite a while now and **I am kind of stuck using an object oriented approach.** I have read things about objects, classes, the solid principles and some tutorials but these often come up with only one single class, like [in this intro](https://medium.com/launch-school/object-oriented-programming-in-ruby-basics-and-definitions-1-2-5917cee58484) (scroll to the very bottom of the page).

Here's the example from the linked website.

My question is how I can implement another class, let's say a Client best?

```
class ClientAccount                                   
  attr_accessor(:id,:limit)                           

  def initialize(id, money, limit)                    
    @id = id                                          
    @money = money                                    
    @limit = limit                                    
  end                                                 

  def below_limit?(limit)                             
    self.money < limit                                
  end

  def alert                                           
    if below_limit?(limit)                            
      puts 'Client has no more money.'                
    else                                              
      puts 'Everything is fine'                       
    end                                               
  end                                                 

  protected                                           

  attr_accessor(:money)                               
end
```

What I want to do is to add one or more class, e.g. the client class below, which interact with the first one like:

> account = ClientAccount.new('x234x19ue24', -245, -150)
>   id = account.read
>   client = Client.new('Mr X', '1.1.1900', **id**)

*This can't be the correct way ...*

Here's the idea of my Client class, I would either put the entire object in the contructor (or as parameter) or I would try to create a singleton(?) ...

```
class Client
  def initialize(name, date_of_birth)
    @name = name
    @date_of_birth = date_of_birth
    @account_id = account_id
  end

  private

  def account
    How can I access the ClientAccount here? Is this the correct way?
  end
end
```

Even more complex if we add a third class, e.g. class ClientXYZ, but for this example two are maybe already enough ...

As you can see, pretty basic things and I would like to know more about the link between several classes. **Currently my own code often feels like procedural code with some objects.** I am sure that there are several approaches but I am really missing a medium level example. Related to the code above, how can I get the `account.read` method into the Client class to fill the account_id.

P.S. Can you give me an example how it could look like? What I could do while working on the code? Or even recommend a good tutorial on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it consistent with the way you developed it, try:

```
class Client
  def initialize(name, date_of_birth, account)
    @name = name
    @date_of_birth = date_of_birth
    @account = account
  end

  private

  def account
    @account
  end

  public

  def alert_on_account
    account.alert
  end
end
```

I also recommend you to read some tutorials available for free on [github](https://github.com/rubymonsters/ruby-for-beginners/tree/main/source).

Answer (score 1):

Tutorials in the form of blog posts only take you so far. They are often targeted to a really specific topic and your mileage will vary. To develop a broader understanding of OOP in Ruby, I suggest the book [Practical Object-Oriented Design: An Agile Primer Using Ruby](https://www.poodr.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I think we have POODR in the company book shelf, will have a look in there.

Comment: The author (Sandi Metz) has another book on OOP that you might find interesting. See: https://www.sandimetz.com/99bottles